# Java JNA UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I am following this tutorial : http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna . The difference is that my class is called main.c not ctest.c. I've created a library inside the project folder as it says there. On the next step i created the Java file with this line modified :

```
CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
```

to

```
CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("main", CTest.class);
```

I have imported jna-4.1.0.jar to my project. On run it gives me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'main': Native library (win32-x86-64/main.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/bin/, file:/D:/eclipse/workspace/RXTX/lib/RXTXcomm.jar, file:/C:/Users/Angelo/Downloads/jna-4.1.0.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:9)
```

Where do i place my main.c and what do i do with the libctest.so file ?

Comment: Do you build `libctest.so` from `main.c`? Then you need to load library `ctest` not `main`. Could you please show how do you compile your `main.c`.

Comment: gcc -o libctest.so -shared main.c     . It will create libctest.so. What do i do with this file ? where should i place it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you build a library `libctest.so`then you need to load it with `CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);` (assuming the rest of your setup is correct).

Where to place the library is described in the [javadoc of the class Native](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html).

To get some hints you might print the steps of the JNA library search to the console.

```
System.setProperty("jna.debug_load", "true"));
CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
```

**edit**

How to call the class (amend the classpath and the directory name)

```
java -classpath jna.jar:. -Djna.library.path=/your/path/to/the/libctest/file HelloWorld
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try it later and i will let you know how i did .

Comment: jna.library.path User-customizable path
jna.platform.library.path Platform-specific paths. I still don't know where are those

Comment: @Ann You have to specify them as JVM option `-Djna.library.path=/your/path/to/the/libctest/file`.

Comment: This is the exact line i have to write in cmd ?

Comment: If you know how is this done, please post exactly what i have to do. I can't figure this out no matter what